# Updating SQLite Boolean field based on Sum of Another Field

Tags: sqlite

I'm having a bit of trouble finessing the SQLite syntax here, and would love it if someone could point me on the right path.

Basically: I'm trying to update a boolean field in one table (MasterItems.InStock) based on the sum of a field in another table (Items.Qty) depending on whether the sum of Qty  in the Items table is > 0 or not.

I can do it in two statements by first:

```
UPDATE MasterItems 
   SET InStock = 0 WHERE InStock <> 0;

UPDATE MasterItems 
   SET InStock = 1 
   WHERE ProductNumber IN
      (SELECT ProductNumber FROM Items
        GROUP BY Items
        HAVING SUM(Qty)> 0);
```

But I know there has to be a way to do it in a single statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean expression, such as "`x > 0`", returns 0 or 1, so you can use it directly.
To update each row with an individual value, use a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). To get a zero when there are no rows for an item, replace the NULL with [ifnull()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
UPDATE MasterItems
SET InStock = (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Qty), 0)
               FROM Items
               WHERE ProductNumber = MasterItems.ProductNumber
              ) > 0;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!